# Unix - Shared Libraries Error

Tags: unix, shared-libraries

When I type `tmadmin -v` I get this error:

```
tmadmin: error while loading shared libraries: libgpnet.so: cannot open shared object   file: No such file or directory
```

`libgpnet.so` is in my `lib` folder. Is there something I need to set so that `tmadmin` look in my `lib` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the path to `lib` directory is present in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. If it's not you can add it as:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib
```